# Best practice to resolve request matched multiple endpoints .NET Core Web api

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have multiple actions on getting a HighScore that require a single integer id. What would be the common best practice to fix the matched multiple endpoints error?

```
[HttpGet("{highScoreId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetHighScoreById(int highScoreId)
{
    var highScore = await _highScoreRepo.GetHighScoreById(highScoreId);

    return Ok(highScore);
}

[HttpGet("{gameId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetHighScoresByGame(int gameId)
{
        var highScores = await _highScoreRepo.GetHighScoresByGame(gameId);
       
        return Ok(highScores);
}
```

Comment: You could always prefix the `HttpGet` route: `[HttpGet("byId/{highScoreId}")]` and `[HttpGet("byGame/{gameId}")]`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use property `Name` an attribute `HttpGetAttribute` for each endpoint

```
[HttpGet("{highScoreId}", Name="GetByHighScoreId")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetHighScoreById(int highScoreId)
{
    var highScore = await _highScoreRepo.GetHighScoreById(highScoreId);

    return Ok(highScore);
}

[HttpGet("{gameId}", Name="GetByGameId")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetHighScoresByGame(int gameId)
{
        var highScores = await _highScoreRepo.GetHighScoresByGame(gameId);
       
        return Ok(highScores);
}
```

or make one endpoint and check the parameters for the absence of a value

```
    [HttpGet()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetHighScore([FromQuery] int? highScoreId = -1, [FromQuery] int? gameId = -1)
    {
        if (highScoreId != -1)
        { 
            var highScore = await _highScoreRepo.GetHighScoreById(highScoreId);

            return Ok(highScore);
        }

        if (gameId != -1)
        {
            var highScores = await _highScoreRepo.GetHighScoresByGame(gameId);

            return Ok(highScores);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
```